# Express Routing basics

Tags: express, parse-platform

I'm just starting with webdev and Express and am confused about the flow.

In my `app.js`:

```
// RESTful routes for the home object.
app.get('/home', homeController.index);
app.get('/home/languages/:id', homeController.languages);
```

In my `home.js` route:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

// Display all users.
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('getAllUsers', {}, {
      success: function(result) {

            console.log("result = " + result);

            res.render('home/index', {
              users: result
            });
      },
      error: function(error) {
          }
    });
};


// Display all the available languages
exports.languages = function(req, res) {
    Parse.Cloud.run('getAllLanguages', {}, {
      success: function(result) {

            res.render('home/languages', {
              languages: result
            });
      },
      error: function(error) {
          }
    });
};
```

Finally, the HTML where I'm trying to display a dropdown with the Language objects:

```
  <div class="page-header" id="languages">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose Language</a>
                  <b class="caret"></b>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

                         <% languages.forEach(function(language) { %>    
                          <li><a href="<%= '/languages/' + language.id %>"><%= language.get("name") %></a></li>   
                        <% }) %>     

                    </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
```

I am able to GET Users and display them fine - I didn't include the HTML for that section. However, I am not routing the GET Languages request correctly as I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: cloud/views/home/index.ejs:17
    15|                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    16| 
 >> 17|                              <% languages.forEach(function(language) { %>    
    18|                               <li><a href="<%= '/languages/' + language.id %>"><%= language.get("name") %></a></li>   
    19|                             <% }) %>     
    20|                            

languages is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (ejs.js:256:12), <anonymous>:33:448)
    at ejs.js:261:15
    at Object.exports.render (ejs.js:299:13)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (ejs.js:325:22)
    at View.render (express_view.js:77:8)
    at Function.app.render (express_application.js:516:10)
    at res.render (express_response.js:763:7)
    at Parse.Cloud.run.success (controllers/home.js:10:10)
    at Parse.js:2:4591
    at r (Parse.js:2:3909)
```

EDIT

This is the second version, which works, and queries for `languages` in the callback from the `users` query.

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {

    console.log("users first");

    Parse.Cloud.run('getAllUsers', {}, {
      success: function(users) {


            Parse.Cloud.run('getAllLanguages', {}, {
              success: function(languages) {

                    res.render('home/index', {
                      languages: languages,
                      users: users
                    });
              },
              error: function(error) {
                  }
            });

      },
      error: function(error) {
          }
    });


};
```

Comment: your routes are fine, do console.log(results) and check is not null or undefined

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon. I included a log statement in the `exports.languages` and it never ran. So I'm pretty sure this function is never called... What I'm confused about is how to call it from the HTML.

Comment: there is something wrong either in your pasted code or your description of the problem, the error am seeing there is caused due to ry to render languages in the index template from your home controller.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem. Both Users and Languages are data that I need to render on the same page. I think this where I'm mixed up. Do I need to chain these calls?... I am trying to render 'Languages' and both 'Users' in the index template in home controller.

Comment: how you do it is up to your implementations, but you need to provide the languages variable. you can chain or you can use promises and execute your call when all the promises are fulfilled.

Comment: OK. I queried for USERS and in the response callback queried for LANGUAGES, and then passed both variables in the render. This worked... What I was trying to do was query for both independently, and then render when each one returned, but I suppose when the second one returned I and rendered the first variable got lost.

Comment: well glad you solved it. if you want more elegant solution look into promises running in parallel i like when.js for promise handling. but there are others.